# Intermittent site failure?

Tags: discussion, bug, error-message, 500-server-error

I think there are multiple people aware of this, but I want to start a question for it to open a discussion and for admins to post relevant details.

I've noticed (and from reading comments here and elsewhere, others have too) that there is an intermittent failure which results in a database error page, or the standard StackOverflow error page. I'll try to screen cap it next time it happens.

I'd assume admins likely already know about this from error logs and server messages. Just wondering what's going on here.

EDIT: So, looking at both the screenshots, it looks like there's really only one error in the back-end. The other screenshot just says that it failed to properly display the error message.

Comment: I have a screen capture of both error pages if you want me to post them.

Comment: Sure! Comment them here and I'll add them to the post.

Comment: Dont bother except for Jon Skeet, we've all seen a YSOD...

Comment: They should post a question on SO to see if anyone knows a solution ;-)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Windows 2008 R2 server clustering on top of which SQL 2012 Always on Availability groups are built is ***buggy as hell***.  We're tracking down the YSOD cause now and attempting to fix before doing the next patch round.

To add to the fun, we've had memory and/or a processor memory controller fail in a server in New York.  Apologies for the errors, but expect more fun...that's why we're doing this on a Sunday night.

*Update:* it wasn't the processor, which we replaced at 3 am, dammit.

*Annnnnnd*, after powering down New York, (but this time on a 15 minute delay, so we were well away from the data center, touché windows) clustering went offline *again*.  But hey! at least we found out a) our NY office building is locked tight after 3am, and b) [our mobile hotspots work](http://twitter.com/GABeech/statuses/290735940106870784).

Comment: Just curious. Is all the traffic pouring in from Reddit and HN right now complicating this? Or is that still just a tiny portion of the entire site's traffic for this time of the day/week?

Comment: @Mysticial - nah we haven't even noticed that traffic...we're doing some patching and shutdown before shutting NY down for the move.  We've had issues with the clustering before, so we opted for a Sunday night operation.

Comment: "we haven't even noticed that traffic" - wow, says something about how much traffic the network gets...

Comment: Good luck, thx for the update, and thanks for staying bleeding edge with a great site!

Comment: Does this impact OCD attempts to get the 100-day every-day login badge? I wanna get that badge...

Comment: Sunday? But it's Monday morning in Finland (Europe), workday started hours ago. Yes, I surf SO to get my work done :)

Comment: @Mysticial According to http://stackexchange.com/sites#traffic, SO gets 4.4M visits per day. Assuming all visits (43k) to your question came in one day, that would still only be around 1% of the traffic SO gets on average

Answer (score 1):

Here are the two related error pages I took a screen shot of when the site went down in the past hour.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks but it only helps if CustomErrors was off or if we were viewing the site from the server - otherwise we cant see the actual error message.

Comment: @JeremyThompson you sort of can, view source for the error page & you'll see the actual error as a HTML comment

Comment: @Sathya That's not particularly doable from a screenshot

Answer (score 1):

Here's another one giving me an error:

- [Equivalents of XDG_CONFIG_HOME and XDG_DATA_HOME on Mac OS X?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3373948/equivalents-of-xdg-config-home-and-xdg-data-home-on-mac-os-x)

immediately redirects to the error page

- https://stackoverflow.com/error?aspxerrorpath=/questions/3373948/equivalents-of-xdg-config-home-and-xdg-data-home-on-mac-os-x

which displays

> Server Error in '/' Application.
> Runtime Error
> Description: An exception occurred while processing your request. Additionally, another exception occurred while executing the custom error page for the first exception. The request has been terminated.

when logged in. In a different browser session (logged out), it seems to hang.

---

It seems chat is also down: https://chat.stackexchange.com/error?aspxerrorpath=/

Back up as of 2013-01-14T08:21Z.

Comment: See the updated answer above for the outage you observed, still - reports appreciated!